# How can I create a ons-switch group?

Tags: onsen-ui

Is there a straight-forward way to create an ons-switch button group so that only ever one switch can be toggled / checked at a given time? Similar to a radio button group. e.g. something like

```
<ons-switch name="my_group_name"></ons-switch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually since the internal input element of a `<ons-switch>` element is a checkbox you will have to write some JavaScript to make them behave like radio buttons.

You could do something like this:

```
var setAll = function(elements, value) {
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].checked = value;
  }
}

var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.switch-group > ons-switch > label > input');

for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    setAll(checkboxes, false);
    this.checked = true;
  });
}
```

It just listens for `change` events and will set all switches to `false` except the clicked one.

This is an example of it in action:

http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/ByyxwX